# Purchase Interest on paid off credit card

Tags: credit-card, canada, interest

I live in Canada. Recently I paid my RBC CC off in full before the monthly due date. On my next bill I incurred interest called "purchase  interest" Why?

Comment: Did you carry a balance from the previous month? What do the terms of your credit card say?

Comment: Did you get a cash advance using this card? Is it possible that you did not pay off the balance in full, or the payment was late?

Comment: Thanks for your response....I did in fact pay the full amount well before the due date. As per your suggestion I went back to the CC company and was told the interest was 'trailing charges' i.e. interest charged per day from the billing cutoff day to the day the payment was received. This would not have happened had I paid my card off in full the previous month. A note of caution for all. The companies find their ways to make money

Comment: The flip side of your question, but this will help you to understand the answers you'll get here - [If I were to buy something a day before my due date for my credit card bill, would I be charged interest?](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/49525/if-i-were-to-buy-something-a-day-before-my-due-date-for-my-credit-card-bill-wou)

Answer (score 4):

The most likely reason that you were charged interest is that you did not pay off the *entire balance* the month before, carrying forward a balance.  Depending on the terms of your credit card, you were charged interest on either the full balance or the remaining balance after your payment.

If that is the case, then you owe the interest.  If that is not the case, or there is some reason why you think you should not have been charged interest, then call customer service and see if they will waive the interest (depending on the amount they may do a one-time waiver), or if they determine you were charged erroneously, ask them to reverse the interest change as well.