# When is the best time to schedule a credit card payment date with Vanquis?

Tags: united-kingdom, credit-card

My credit card arrives in a few days so I am unsure of my statement date and payment due date, although I know I am able to change my payment due date. I am paid the 18th of every month and ideally I wanted to pay off my credit card on this date in full once I start using it. I was thinking of scheduling it for the 25th so I knew the funds would’ve definitely gone through, but I am unsure as I’ve never had a credit card before.

If I pay off any outstanding funds on the 18th, and my payment due date is the 25th, when can I use my card again? Or, what dates are best to use the card? There are 25 days between my statement date and payment due date.

Any other help would be appreciated!!

Comment: [If I were to buy something a day before my due date for my credit card bill, would I be charged interest?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/49525/if-i-were-to-buy-something-a-day-before-my-due-date-for-my-credit-card-bill-wou) might be helpful, not quite an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

I only have experience with US credit cards, but from other's answers and comments, it sounds like this holds true for the UK as well.

I see no benefit in scheduling your credit card payment for any particular day. If you are living paycheck to paycheck then your suggested schedule seems reasonable.

> If I pay off any outstanding funds on the 18th, and my payment due date is the 25th, when can I use my card again?

You never need to stop using your card.

After one month of using your card, you will get a bill for all the purchases you made during that month. You will have a few weeks to pay off this bill. If you pay the bill in full before the bill is due, you will pay no interest. This is the optimal strategy for paying off a credit card. No need to stop using the card before you pay the bill. The charges will just show up on your next bill.

There is one caveat. At no point should you attempt to exceed your credit limit. If you are approaching the limit, then you should stop using the card until you have made a payment.

Comment: It works the same in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checking that you are correct in being able to set your *payment due date*. On UK credit cards, paid off by direct debit, it is normally possible to set your *payment date*, but I've never heard of being able to set your *payment due date*. You just need to make sure your *payment date* is before your *payment due date*, though I suspect the system would force that anyway.

As far as spending, [Matt's answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/107200/28861) holds true for the UK. Here's an example:

- Let's say I opened the credit card account on the 17th of March, and have a credit limit of £1000.
- From the 17th of March to the 16th of April I spend a total of £300
- On the 18th of April I spend £100
- On the 19th of April I receive my statement, saying that I need to pay a minimum of £30 by 10th of May, or £300 to avoid interest
- Between 20th April and 9th May I spend another £500. My balance is then £900, still below my £1000 limit so ok
- On 10th May my direct debit pays off the £300 for the 19th April statement. My balance drops to £600
- From 11th May to 16th May I spend another £350, taking my balance to £950. I can't spend more than £50 until I pay some of it off
- On 19th May I receive my new statement, saying I owe £950. I still can't spend more than £50 until I pay some of it off. That means I either wait until my direct debit on 10th June, or I make an additional one-off payment at any time I want

*Dates are all approximate, I can't be bothered to work out actual dates between periods, statements and pauments*